# How to install the ncursesw development libraries

Tags: linux, ncurses

I'm trying to follow the instructions in

https://github.com/flok99/multitail/blob/master/INSTALL

It says to install the "ncursesw development libraries"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 45):

It depends on your distro:

On Debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev`

On RedHat/Fedora/CentOS, `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`

Comment: For me, dnf was reporting it was already installed, however that was only the x32 version. `sudo dnf install ncurses-devel.x86_64` did the trick finally.

Answer (score 4):

For most of the users, who do not have root privileges, can install and include ncursesw lib in this way.

- 1. download ncurses

```bash
wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.3.tar.gz"
```

- 2. compile and install ncurse into customized path

```bash
tar zxvf ncurses-6.3.tar.gz
cd ncurses-6.3
# customize your installation path
export LIB_PATH=$HOME/.local 
./configure  --prefix=${LIB_PATH} --enable-widec --with-shared  --with-cxx-shared
make && make install
```

- 3. specify the ncurses libs when you install other software that based on ncurese.

```bash
CFLAGS=-I${LIB_PATH}/include LDFLAGS=-L${LIB_PATH}/lib ./configure
make && make install
```