# ncurses.h extended characters not displaying properly in c

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to pretty up my program by using ncurses extended characters. However, some of them show up as the question mark in a box: ⍰. This happens when I try functions such as:

```
addch(ACS_S1);
addch(ACS_LANTERN);
addch(ACS_S3);
```

And so on. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();

  addch(ACS_S1);
  addch(ACS_S3);
  addch(ACS_S7);
  addch(ACS_S9);
  addch(ACS_LANTERN);

  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

edit: I forgot to add the code example. So I added it this time
edit: I am using Ubuntu to compile my code

Comment: If you can, post a minimal `main()` that people can quickly try themselves.

Comment: What is the execution environment?

Comment: @Clifford I am using Ubunutu to compile my code

Comment: @NikosC. Hey thanks I forgot to add it. I just added it

Comment: It is likely that these characters are not representable by the 8-bit `chtype` parameter of `addch()`.  Perhaps [`add_wch(WACS_LANTERN)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/add_wch.3ncurses.html)

Comment: @Clifford I tried that out, but that just gave errors: undeclared (first use in function).  Do you know of any character printing functions that are maybe 12 bit or 16 bit? I believe the extended ASCII table/ncurses characters are up to 255, so I really only need a 9 bit character printer

Comment: Well it is there in the man page, so the lack of declaration in curses.h is perhaps a different question.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186824/how-to-install-the-ncursesw-development-libraries for wide character support?

Comment: @Clifford alright so I gave that a try. Firstly thank you, because I was missing over 100 different packages that kept giving me errors to install. That being said, my original problem has still not been fixed. They keep showing up as the question mark boxes

Comment: Is your terminal using a font that has these characters? Maybe it's a font issue. Try using a different font. I'm using the "dylex terminal 13pt" font and the characters show up correctly for me with the test program you provided.

Comment: @NikosC. I'd like to try what you are suggesting, but I don't know the command in Ubuntu to change the font size. I typed "dylex terminal 13pt" into the command line, but it doesn't recognize "dylex". So a follow-up would be very appreciated

Comment: It's the terminal's application settings. (I guess you're using Gnome Terminal.)

Comment: @NikosC. I just downloaded unity-control-center & gnome-control-center to attempt to access the terminal application settings. I don't know how else to access the terminal application settings

Comment: Can't you just right-click on the terminal window to get a menu? Or just use the application menu?

Comment: @NikosC. lol yea you can that's so funny. I'll adjust it to 13, but it automatically is set at 16. So I messed around with the settings a bit, and the issue isn't the size, but the Font Type. I use\ Consolas, and that's giving me a problem. But using others fixed my issue with that. While this information fixes some problems, it only causes others because now the rest of my art looks wonky. But this did help so thank you

Comment: Consolas is a Microsoft font though right? I don't think it was made to support Unix text-mode special character stuff like this :P

Comment: @NikosC. I have no idea. It was what Ubunutu had as the default font. I am going to experiment now with the different fonts and which ones work. By any chance do you know how to add other fonts to Ubuntu? Because right now I only have like 5 or 6 that I can choose from

Comment: I just copy them to the `.fonts`  directory in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to **[tell](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization)** ncurses what the locale is (and if you did not compile/link with ncursesw, there are still some [limitations](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS)):

> The  library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized.
>          That is normally done with **`setlocale`**:
>
> `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`
>
> If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes  that  characters
>   are  printable  as in ISO-8859-1, to work with certain legacy programs.
>   You should initialize the locale and not rely on  specific  details  of
>   the library when the locale has not been setup.

Comment: Thanks for leaving this. I added the <locale.h> library, and added the function "setlocale(LC_ALL, "");" like you had in your answer. I don't think I understand your answer however. It still isn't fixing my issue of ncurses printing out the question mark box. I tried adding -lncursesw to my compile line and that still gave me the question mark box. You may have very well answered it in the answer you provided, but I am not versed enough in programmer lingo to understand fully what you wrote.